# why python find not working

Tags: python, find

i am using *python 2.5.2*. The following code not working.

```
def findValue(self, text, findText):
     index = text.find(findText)
     print index
```

Although the `findText` is present in `text`, but it still returns `None`.

I have printed the values of `text` and `findText` and they are present.

**Edit**: I have fixed the issue.

The problem was i am calling code like

```
for i in arr:
      self.findValue(i,"someText")
```

As type of `i` is `instance` so this does not work. I have just changed it to:

```
self.findValue(str(i),"someText")
```

Comment: What are the values of text and findText that you are using?

Comment: Can you give a short but complete example of this failing? Something we can run ourselves?

Comment: Can any one delete this question as the question because i am unable to pick any answer

Comment: @user283405: you are allowed to post your own answer and select it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

The problem was i am calling code like

```
for i in arr: 
      self.findValue(i,"someText")
```

As type of `i` is instance so this does not work. I have just changed it to:

```
self.findValue(str(i),"someText")
```

Answer (score 5):

You aren't returning a value from your function, you are only printing it. This means that the return value for the function will be None.

Try adding `return index`at the end of your code.

```
def myfind(self, text, findText):
     index = text.find(findText)
     return index
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't automatically return the last variable, you need to explicitly use `return index`

And If the `.find` is failing, it should return `-1` instead of `None`, So most probably, problem is in your return part, not in the `.find`